# The type conversion of inheritance type between the Generics type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

```
List<List<object>> all = new List<List<object>>();
List<string> k = new List<string>();
all.Add(k);
```

The error is "**cannot convert from `List<string>` to `List<object>`**. "

I wonder how to transform type like these.

Comment: They are not the same thing. You're allowed to add an `int` to a `List<object>` but not to a `List<string>`, so there is no conversion possible. Look up covariance, contravariance and invariance. There are plenty of questions on this subject on SO already.

Comment: You could create a new `List<object>` containing all the strings from your `List<string>` and add that new list to your list of object lists, but it would be a completely new list so not sure if that falls in your definition of "transformation"

Answer (score 1):

You would have to cast your list of string to objects
Here is a simple solution

```
List<List<object>> all = new List<List<object>>();
List<string> k = new List<string>();
all.Add(k.Cast<object>().ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

`List<T>` implements non-generic [IList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist?view=net-5.0) interface, so depending on your purpose it is possible to use `List<IList>()` list:

```
var all = new List<IList>();
var k = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
var num = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
all.Add(k);
all.Add(num);
string b = (string)all[0][1]; // "b"
int two = (int)all[1][1]; // 2
```